# Import same python module more than once

Tags: python, import, module, pygame

I am trying to find a way of importing the same module more than once due to a certain key press....

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_1:
        import forest_level
    if event.key == pygame.K_2:
        import sea_level
    if event.key == pygame.K_3:
        import desert_level
    if event.key == pygame.K_4:
        import underwater_level
    if event.key == pygame.K_5:
        import space_level
```

say if I were in the forest level and went to the sea level, how would I get back to forest level?

**[GAME CODE](http://pastebin.com/jNpX3VrM)**

Comment: A module is imported only once, the later imports simply fetch the already imported module object from `sys.modules`. You'll have to use `reload()` to force Python to reload a already imported module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

I'm going to have to guess the structure of your code, since you havent quite provided a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

You probably have several modules that look like:

```
# foo_level.py
print "foo"
```

along with a main module:

```
# main.py
while True:
    key = raw_input()
    if key == "foo":
        import foo_level
    # and so on.
```

the `import` statement is designed for bringing code into scope, not for actually executing any code.

Put all of the code you want to run multiple times in a function:

```
# foo_level.py
def do_stuff():
    print "foo"
```

and instead, import all modules once, at the beginning and call the new functions inside the loop:

```
# main.py
import foo_level
while True:
    key = raw_input()
    if key == "foo":
        foo_level.do_stuff()
    # and so on.
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this, so your saying create a new module with all the levels defined it and then another module which allows you to call the levels in from the newly created one?