# Doubts on openpyxl, python3

Tags: python-3.x

He guys, I am just a beginner in Python3. I have a question :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.style import *
```

As you can see that I am importing the **openpyxl** module, but why I need to import the second one in order to style **fonts** and **cells** an on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import same python module more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241668/import-same-python-module-more-than-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openpyxl` is a package. It contains modules, such as `style`. You should import the package anyway (all package or individual items). You can either:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.style import *
```

then use style items like `item1`, `item2`
or

```
from openpyxl import style
```

then use style items like `style.item1`, `style.item2`

Comment: I thought openpyxl is an module

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to - you can just as easily do:

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.styles.fonts()
```

Or:

```
from openpyxl import style
style.fonts()
```

It comes down to personal preference. Using `*` imports is generally frowned upon because there's a risk of polluting the namespace, but if you know this isn't going to happen, and you want to keep your lines of code shorter, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing openpyxl, which includes everything in openpyxl including openpyxl.style and everything inside that. But say you would like to use X function of openpyxl.style, then you would have to write:

```
openpyxl.style.X()
```

If you write the second line you can simpy write:

```
X()
```

Basically the second line imports all the contents of the namespace openpyxl.style into your current namespace, removing the hassle of having to write openpyxl.style. everytime. Although it is generally a good practice to not merge namespaces like this, and not use

```
from _________ import *
```

Rather you can write

```
import openpyxl.style as op
```

and then use the X function as :

```
op.X()
```

You can also omit the line

```
import openpyxl
```

if you are not using anything else from openpyxl other than that included in openpyxl.style